# How to make part of text that is on an image a different color on hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover, gsap, web-animations

[example of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v854H.png)

https://dribbble.com/shots/15453707-Si-Design-P-C-Homepage-Motion

I saw this example on dribbble where if you hover over the image, the text appears. The text is black on the white background and white on the image. I've tried using mixed-blend but that doesn't give the same result. Any suggestions on how this was achieved.

Comment: Its mix-blend-mode, please add [mre] for your example